# Using Tcl with Jupyter notebook

Tags: tcl, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded Anaconda, and have been using Jupyter notebook. Now I would like to use it with Tcl.  I followed the instructions at https://github.com/rpep/tcl_kernel, (which is to pip3 install tcl_kernel).
It has installed in AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32.
However, Tcl does not appear as an option for a new notebook.
Can anyone advise?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Tcl on Jupyter Notebook: intel offers a package to be used on Jupyter Notebook, where you can develop your projects and view the result of the codes.

To perform the installation (linux), type the following command in the terminal:

conda install -c intel tcl

pip3 install tcl_kernel

python3 -m tcl_kernel.install

conda update conda

Link of the pages so that you can search for the equivalent packages on Win / Mac:

https://anaconda.org/intel/tcl

https://github.com/rpep/tcl_kernel

Ready! When accessing Jupyter Notebook, select the Tcl option in the 'New' section.

There are versions for various Operating Systems. I chose Linux because it is the only one on computers here at home.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that kernel listed under 'new' -- but if I open another notebook and try the 'kernel' menu, there is a 'change kernel' item that does the job.